# Stop Emoji Being Entered In Input Fields

Tags: c#, jquery, html, forms, emoji

I need to know how you can stop a tablet or mobile user from entering emojis in any `input type="text"` field as users abe able to submit my form but it causes errors in my middle tier as they come through as squares and also writes to my DB as squares.

Cant seem to find a solution on Google so thought id ask on here.

Is there an HTML attribute i can use of something?

Comment: Depending on your database backend you could also use an `utf8_unicode_bin` equivalent encoding and your db will be able to handle emoji just fine. (as long as you don't assume 1 char to be 1 byte long)

Comment: @Kris I dont want emojis at all.

Comment: perhaps, but you might want other unicode benefits now or down the line, like chinese, japanese, hangul, arabic, etc. support

Comment: @Kris The website is only supported by english and only ever will be hence why i dont need to think of other languages

Comment: that's perfectly fine and exactly why I also answered your actual question. I still have to give these types of suggestions because more often than not people don't know that they are trying to solve "the wrong" problem. Only trying to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a better idea to make your database compatible by changing encoding.

That being said, you could loop over all characters in the textfield and make sure that their ordinal is between 32 and 255 inclusive. This would make it so that you only allow printable ASCII characters, more than enough for any English text.

Something like this: (untested, typed in textarea)

```
function stripNonAscii(input) {
    let output = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let c = input.charCodeAt(i);
        if(c >= 32 && c <= 255) {
            output += input.substring(i, 1);
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Should/could double-check on the backend during form processing also.